# net view troubles in cmd

Tags: web-services, networking, cmd, windows-xp, file-sharing

Ok so ive been looking online with no luck to find an answer to fixing my **net view** command issue. The error is as follows:

```
 C:\windows\system32>net view_
 There are no entries in the list

 C:\windows\system32>_
```

Now from what ive read online this is caused when the guest account on a winNT machine is not enabled and is set to be the backup browser for the network. Two problems... I have no Windows NT Machine, i have no "computer browser backup". So i have no clue as to what i need to do in order to get this up and running. I have enabled **file sharing** and the **computer browser** under ***services.msc*** with no luck of showing the computers on my network. They are also all connected through the same workgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NetBIOS to work properly the following ports must be open on all hosts:

```
137/udp (NetBIOS Name Service)
138/udp (NetBIOS Datagram Distribution Service)
139/tcp (NetBIOS Session Service)
```

I'd recommend opening `445/tcp` (Direct SMB) as well.

If you have the Windows Firewall enabled, you must add exceptions for all of these ports.